# scipy.special yields fluctuating result for confluent hypergeometric function

Tags: scipy

The scipy implementation of the confluent hypergeometric function gives me wrong results. This is a minimal code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import special

x=np.arange(0,1,.001)
f=special.hyp1f1(30,60,-1/x)
plt.scatter(x,f,s=.05)
```

When I run it, it produces the following plot:

[output of scipy.special.hyp1f1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lybKo.png)

I wonder if there is a way to fix these fluctuations, which are definitely not correct. In fact, the function should be strictly positive in that range.

Comment: What is it suppose to produce? Just a line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the explanation at [scipy.special.hyp1f1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.hyp1f1.html), here is an attempt to approximate the function with a [polynomial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html#numpy.poly1d).

Apparently, `hyp1f1(-1/x)` works nice between `x=0` and about `x=0.2`. Note that at x exactly 0, the function isn't properly defined.  The approximation with a 5th degree polynomial is much too large for `x<0.4`. With a 80th degree polynomial, the approximation seems correct starting at `x>0.025` but quickly gets out of bounds for smaller `x`. (With more than 90 terms the polynomial can't be calculated in this way anymore.)

Probably the best solution would be to use a high degree polynomial for `x>=0.1` and the original `hyp1f1` when x is smaller.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import special

x = np.linspace(0.001, 1, 1000)

f = special.hyp1f1(30, 60, -1 / x)
plt.scatter(x, f, s=1, color='r', label='hyp1f1')

for terms in range(80, 1, -10):
    k10 = np.arange(terms)
    c10 = special.poch(30, k10) / (special.poch(60, k10) * special.factorial(k10))

    poly10 = np.poly1d(c10[::-1])
    plt.scatter(x, poly10(-1 / x), s=1, label=f'{terms} terms', color=plt.cm.Set1(terms / 80))

plt.ylim(-3.5, 3.7)
plt.legend(scatterpoints=10, ncol=3)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Zoomed in:

[image: zoomed plot]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.